# How to Convert Calculation String to Double

Tags: c#, .net, string

Following string in my input

```
"(((5292-5325)-(5401/5))/5325)"
```

I need to calculate this one and wants to get output in `float`. For that I used `string` to `float` conversion but I got exception. how to do that one?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: What exception? What code?

Comment: You can use [wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((5292-5325)-(5401%2F5))%2F5325)) if you need to calculate such a thing. If you want to do it in c# code, please share what you got so far and what research you already done to deal with problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose usually:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var result = dt.Compute("(((5292-5325)-(5401/5))/5325)", "");
```

Or:

```
double result = (double)dt.Compute("(((5292-5325)-(5401/5))/5325)", "");
```

Comment: Wow - I never knew that.

Answer (score 0):

Can quickly think of 2 ways:

1. Faster - Use Spring.Net (specially the Spring.Expressions) which has ExpressionEvaluator that might be able to help in this case
2. Tedious - Make your own code that does the expression parsing & evaluation.
   Read About Infix Expression evaluation.